# Setting actionbar of new activity from mainactivity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-activity, android-imagebutton

this might be trivial, but I still hope you can help me. 
My MainActivity is a list, where each row consists of an imagebutton on the left side and a text on the right side. Each row has another image and text.
When clicking on the button, a new activity opens and I want the actionbar to have the respective image of the button clicked and the text of the respective row of my MainActivity. 
How can I dynamically change the ressources based on the different buttons?

Thank you for your help

Comment: pass the resource ids while calling intent

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325875/update-actionbar-from-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to pass data to second Activity and use `getIntent()` method to get passed information in second activity, you can change ActionBar title using `setTitle()` method and you can change icon by using `setIcon()` method.